Minimum Spanning Tree clustering with only edge weights?
I have data that has been used to fit a Bayesian non-parametric mixture model.  One of the things I can do with that is sample conditional posterior cluster assignments.  Given a sufficiently large sample, I've used that to calculate a similarity matrix--that is, a (n x n) matrix of pairwise probabilities of falling into the same cluster.
Using that as a set of edge weights, I want to label emergent clusters.  One thing I was looking at is MST--minimum spanning tree clustering, as an algorithm.  But every MST algorithm I see implemented seems to be working in parameter space, and using that to calculate the edge weights.  I already have the edge weights calculated, and want to use them to build the tree.
Are there any such algorithms implemented?
